# Two pieces of JavaScript code with the same purpose and idea produce a different effect

Tags: javascript

`

```
function string2int(s) {
    var arr = [];
    for (let x of s) {
        arr.push(x);
    }
    
    arr.map(function (x) {return x*1;});
    var result = arr.reduce(function (x, y) {return x*10 + y;});
    alert(result);
}
string2int('123456');
```

`

`

```
function string2int(s) {
    var arr = [];
    for (let x of s) {
        arr.push(x*1);
    }
    
    var result = arr.reduce(function (x, y) {return x*10 + y;});
    alert(result);
}
string2int('123456');
```

`

As shown by the name of the function name string2int, the purpose of both two pieces of code is to transform string '123456' into int 123456, the idea is to trasform '123456' into arr(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']) firstly, then use each char to multiply 1 to turn elements in the array arr into int, and finally use reduce function to get the expected int 1234156. However, it turned out that only the second piece of code worked properly, the first piece would output the result 10203040506.

I added alert(arr); under arr.map(function (x) {return x*1;}); in the first piece of code and found that even after the execution of map function, elements in array arr were still int type, why is this? Besides, in that case, how was the final result 10203040506 got?

Comment: `Array.prototype.map` does not mutate the array, but returns a new array. Else said, if the argument is a pure function (which it should be), not assigning it anywhere is a no-op.

Comment: `string2int` <-- why reinvent the wheel? JS has `parseInt` and the `Number` constructor accepts `string` input too.

Comment: why torture yourself when javascript has `Number` that can convert string to number? just do this `const result = Number("123456");`

Comment: You have to do this: `x*10 + y*1`. Else, it will be string addition and not number addition.

Comment: @Layhout for learning

Comment: Afterwards, you don't provide `Array.prototype.reduce` an argument for the initial value, therefore it uses the first array element, which is a string. After that, even though `x * 10` converts to `number`, the following addition will go back to string.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Thanks a lot for your answer, it really solves my puzzle directly and is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @vighnesh153 Hello, thank you a lot for your answer, combining your comment with ASDFGerte's helps me to figure out what is wrong with my code.

Comment: @Dai Hi, Dai, I started to learn JavaScript yesterday by following a course, this problem is a task in the course and I am not allowed to use parseInt or Number. Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Layhout Hi, Layout, I started to learn JavaScript yesterday by following a course, this problem is a task in the course and I am not allowed to use parseInt or Number. Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the first part is that you are using the **map** method, which returns a new array and will never change the original **arr** array. By doing so, your items inside arr will still be of type 'string', and also the variable **result**. You can verify this by adding this to the last line of the first function:

```
console.log(typeof result);
```

In order for your code to work, you will need to declare a new variable for the map method to return, and then work the reduce method on it. Example:

```
let newArr = arr.map(function (x) {return x*2;});
var result = newArr.reduce(function (x, y) {return x*10 + y;});
```

Edit: Alternatively you could use the **forEach** method instead of **map**, and the original array **arr** would be changed.

Answer (score 0):

The first function fails to convert digits (strings that represent numerals) into into ints. The least invasive fix is to do that conversion as the digits are pushed to `arr` with a unary `+`...

```js
function string2int(s) {
    var arr = [];
    for (let x of s) {
        arr.push(+x);    // convert to int here
    }
    
    // arr.map(function (x) {return x*1;});  // this does nothing
    var result = arr.reduce(function (x, y) {return x*10 + y;});
    alert(result);
}
string2int('123456');
```

It can be improved by realizing that `split('')` does the work of the first loop, and that conversion to ints from digits can happen in the reduce...

```js
function string2int(s) {
  return s.split('').reduce((a, digit) => a*10 + +digit, 0)
}
alert(string2int('123456'));
```